# Any nice/good way to allow an "or" option in a linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am looking for a way to express an "or" option in a system of linear inequalities for a linear program I am working on.

I will explain what I mean precisely: Lets say I have a set of inequalities $eq_1$ to $eq_n$, which must hold.  But, additionally, I have several more inequalities $eqa_1,....,eqa_k$ and $eqb_1,...,eqb_k$, that can be partitioned to couples (of the form $\left< eqa_i ,\, eqb_i\right>$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$), such that either $eqa_i$ holds or if it doesn't then $eqb_i$. Nonetheless, it is also possible for both of them to hold. What I am looking for is an option to encode such an "or" condition on a set of inequalities.

Ofcourse, if we say that $eqa_i$ is lets say $f\left(...\right) \leq K$ and $eqb_i$ is $g\left(...\right) \leq M$ I can write $f\left(...\right)+g\left(...\right) \leq K+M$, but this demand is too strong, because in my original problem I may allow $f\left(...\right) > K+M$ (for example) as long as $g\left(...\right) \leq M$, but then $f\left(...\right)+g\left(...\right) > K+M$. So requiring $f\left(...\right)+g\left(...\right) \leq K+M$ is too strong for me.

My question can be divided to 2 questions:

1. Is there any idea for a nice trick here or for some sort of a reduction to Linear Programming? (A reduction from an instance in which you have couples of inequalities with an or, to a regular instance of LP)
2. Perhaps there exists a software or an online site which allow this kind of "or"? I am using this site: https://online-optimizer.appspot.com/. However, if there are other sites or software which have such a built in option for an "or", it'd be great as well.

If my inequalities are too generic, I know that most of them  seem from the form $x_{i_1}+x_{i_2}+x_{i_3} \leq K$, where $K$ is the same $K$ for all the inequalities, and the rest are either $x_{i_1}+x_{i_2} \leq K$ or $x_{i_1}+x_{i_2}+x_{i_3}+x_{i_4} \leq K$.

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no "nice" way to do it.  Geometrically the "or" introduces a union of domains, so what would be a convex polytope with only "and" linear inequalities will instead turn into a union of such things, and probably not convex.  The general recourse would be to compare the results of solving separate problems, corresponding to the "or" cases.  If you were looking for a maximum value, then you'd take the maximum of results for all the separate subproblems.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/380484/37212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enforce $f \le K \lor g \le M$ by introducing a binary decision variable $x$ and linear "big-M" constraints:
\begin{align}
f - K &\le M_1 x \tag1 \\
g - M &\le M_2(1-x) \tag2
\end{align}
Here $M_1$ is a constant upper bound on $f-K$ when $x=1$, and $M_2$ is a constant upper bound on $g-M$ when $x=0$.

If $x=0$, then constraint $(1)$ forces $f \le K$ and constraint $(2)$ is redundant.
If $x=1$, then constraint $(2)$ forces $g \le M$ and constraint $(1)$ is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But there are 2 issues that bother me here. First, this does not seem to be a linear program, due to the multiplication $M_1$ by $x$ in $(1)$ (and also in $(2)$...). The second issue is regarding the idea itself. if $x=0$ then $(1)$ is $f \leq K$ but why is $(2)$ redundant? Because $M_2$ can be negative or positive and then we don't know whether $g\leq M$ or $g\geq M$? (Im just asking to verify I understand your idea). However, I still think this is not a linear program?

Comment: $M_1$ and $M_2$ are constants chosen by you, so the constraints are linear.  The resulting problem is a mixed integer linear program. If $x=0$, then $(2)$ is redundant by the choice of $M_2$ as an upper bound on $g-M$.